How to custom cpp var value in gdb and clion > watches
see my img, I find zoned_time can show custom str "America/New_York" 1721904914882986761ns [2024-07-25 10:55:14]

how to custom this value in my own class
I try following code but it only show type in clion watches
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class DraftTest : public testing::Test {
protected:
    // Set up common test data or state if needed
};

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int a, double b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}

    // Define how the class should be printed
    std::string toString() const {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "MyClass(a=" << a_ << ", b=" << b_ << ")";
        return ss.str();
    }

    // Provide a way to print using `<<`
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass &obj) {
        return os << obj.toString();
    }

private:
    int a_;
    double b_;
};


TEST_F(DraftTest, test_video) {
    MyClass obj(1, 2.5);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl; // Will use the `<<` operator to print `obj`
    // Use obj in your test as needed
}



Have you tried clikcking on the > to the left of your variable? Is that not good enough?

@john, yes click ">" can show detail, just wanna know how to customize clion watched value like std::chrono

The general term for this is 'natvis'. But natvis is a Microsoft product for their debugger. I have heard that it has been ported to gdb, but I have also heard that it doesn't work very well. So I can't offer any solution, only something you can google for.

Or you could look at this. Seems to be how it's done for gdb.
